# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while using model.fit

Tags: keras

def train(self):
self.model.fit([self.graph_train, self.pattern_train], self.y_train batch_size=self.batch_size,epochs=self.epochs,
class_weight=self.class_weight)

[Getting Error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2qCl.png)

Comment: Did you search the answer here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous